# Wireless Ad Hoc NAT

Tags: usb, wifi

I got "OURLiNK 802.11n" mini USB wifi adapter for my Raspberry Pi, but I also would like to use it w/ my Scientific Linux 6.1

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Scientific Linux release 6.1 (Carbon)
$
```

when I insert dongle into USB port, I'm getting following in my log

```
Oct 18 11:16:28 X kernel: usb 1-4: new high speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
Oct 18 11:16:28 X kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8176
Oct 18 11:16:28 X kernel: usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct 18 11:16:28 X kernel: usb 1-4: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Oct 18 11:16:28 X kernel: usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Realtek
Oct 18 11:16:28 X kernel: usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
Oct 18 11:16:28 X kernel: usb 1-4: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
```

I added a connection through: System->Preferences->Network Connections->Wireless->Add using Ad-hoc mode, I even did `service network restart`, yet I still don't see SSID from another wireless device.

I'd like to be able to configure NATing on my Linux so that other devices can use that connection to connect to Internet.